# Problems writing to pipe in ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-streaming, windows-server-2016

I have written a stream server that utilizes FFMPEG for transcoding. [StreamServer2 v.1.5]

The way it works is that i have thru a control channel tell a DVR to open a stream, when the stream is open the DVR will respond with a sdp file- or the info for the sdp file.
This is working when i run StreamServer2 on my windows 10 computer, byt when i run it on my 2016 server, i get an error saying: `Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

I works on my Windows 10 computer, also I have an old version of StreamServer2 from before we created the control channel; that one is opning a RTSP stream as you normally will do, bu calling the rtsp url, and that is currently running live  on an server 2008R2 environment.

The reason that we did change the way of getting a stream is that we have a new system where the DVRs IPAddress is dynamic and unpredictable.

So i hope that somebody can help me find out why it does not work on Windows Server 2016

**The FFMPG Report file**

```
ffmpeg started on 2018-06-27 at 13:06:51
Report written to "ffmpeg-20180627-130651.log"
Command line:
"E:\\r2pPrograms\\StreamServer2\\ffmpeg.exe" -stdin -y -loglevel info -report -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i 8936021605650268160_37.sdp -f mpeg1video -g 52 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -b:v 64k -q 5 -an -
ffmpeg version N-91024-g293a6e8332 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.101 / 58. 19.101
  libavformat    58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-stdin' ... matched as option 'stdin' (enable or disable interaction on standard input) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'info'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ... matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file,udp,rtp'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '8936021605650268160_37.sdp'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mpeg1video'.
Reading option '-g' ... matched as AVOption 'g' with argument '52'.
Reading option '-movflags' ... matched as AVOption 'movflags' with argument 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov'.
Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '64k'.
Reading option '-q' ... matched as option 'q' (use fixed quality scale (VBR)) with argument '5'.
Reading option '-an' ... matched as option 'an' (disable audio) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option stdin (enable or disable interaction on standard input) with argument 1.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument info.
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url 8936021605650268160_37.sdp.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: 8936021605650268160_37.sdp.
[NULL @ 000001484256c1c0] Opening '8936021605650268160_37.sdp' for reading
[sdp @ 000001484256c1c0] Format sdp probed with size=2048 and score=50
[sdp @ 000001484256c1c0] video codec set to: h264
[udp @ 0000014842572700] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 0000014842572700] end receive buffer size reported is 65536
[udp @ 000001484258f140] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required)
[udp @ 000001484258f140] end receive buffer size reported is 65536
[sdp @ 000001484256c1c0] setting jitter buffer size to 500
[sdp @ 000001484256c1c0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 152 bytes read:152 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[sdp @ 000001484256c1c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[sdp @ 000001484256c1c0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 152 bytes read:152 seeks:0 frames:0
Input #0, sdp, from '8936021605650268160_37.sdp':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url -.
Applying option f (force format) with argument mpeg1video.
Applying option b:v (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument 64k.
Applying option q (use fixed quality scale (VBR)) with argument 5.
Applying option an (disable audio) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: -.
Output #0, mpeg1video, to 'pipe:':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
[AVIOContext @ 0000014842574b80] Statistics: 152 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Comment: `Could not find codec parameters for stream 0` --> this is the proximate cause. Add `-analyzeduration 15M` before `-i` and check.

Comment: Thanks, @Gyan, But i think you did not read my question properly. I do not need ffmpeg to find the codec parameters for the input stream. My codec parameters are defined in the sdp file not in the stream itself. That line is there by design, and is also there when i run it on my computer, but on my computer it works. If you read the log, you will  also see that it has found the codec in the sdp file

Comment: If sprop-parameter-sets is present in the SDP, ffmpeg hasn't used it to initialize the decoder, so the diagnosis still stands.

Comment: @Guan, as i told you the same line is present, when running the system locally on my computer. It works on my computer and i just tested on the Old 2008R2 Server it also works there. From the log on my computer [See this image](https://imgur.com/a/hFtTfPv)